# ¿Nodemailer no funciona en heroku?

Tags: nodejs, heroku, requests, nodemailer

Cuando pruebo mi backend en el localhost, funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo despliego en heroku me manda el siguien error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://chango-tareas-backend.herokuapp.com/api/send-email' from
> origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Esta es la linea de codigo encargarda de enviar correos a traves de nodemailer

```
//ruta para enviar el correo con nodemailer
router.post('/send-email', cors(), async (req, res) => {

    const { nombre, email, mensaje, url, destino } = req.body;

    contentHtml = `
        <h1>CV solicitante ${nombre}<h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Contactar a: ${email}</li>
            <li>${mensaje}</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="${url}">Click para ver</a>
    `;

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'host_outlock',
        port: port,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'micorreo@hotmail.com',
            pass: 'mipassword'
        }
    });

    try{
        const info = await transporter.sendMail({
            from: "'ChangoTareas' <abisur_yue@hotmail.com>",
            to: `${destino}`,
            subject: `Solicitud de registro ${nombre}`,
            text: 'Hola guapo :v',
            html: contentHtml
        });
    }catch(err){
        next(err);
    }
        
    console.log('Message sent', info.messageId);

    res.status(200).send({ data: 'Success' });
});
```

En el console log de heroku me arroja las siguientes excepciones

> 2021-01-19T04:35:32.154277+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:36)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: next is not defined
> 2021-01-19T04:35:32.154291+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
> /app/src/routes/index.js:128:9 2021-01-19T04:35:32.154292+00:00
> app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> 2021-01-19T04:35:32.154416+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:36)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) 2021-01-19T04:35:32.154521+00:00 app[web.1]:
> (node:36) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
> are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
> will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
> 2021-01-19T04:35:54.733967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12
> desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/send-email"
> host=chango-tareas-backend.herokuapp.com
> request_id=ba1f5e44-615f-4545-ab66-254db83c67a1 fwd="187.227.25.218"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
> protocol=https

Answer (score 1):

Los logs de heroku señalan que te falta un parametro en el callback de tu ruta. Agrega el tercer parametro `next`.

```
router.post('/send-email', cors(), async (req, res, next) => {...
```

Esto es necesario por que el código que presentas, en el bloque catch, brinca a otro controlador (en este caso un global de errores) con `next(error)`. Esto debería solucionar el problema de cors también, ya que heroku manda una petición extraña a la original lo que activa la protección por cors en el navegador.